# How to Connect Hibernate and Drools

Tags: java, hibernate, drools, rule-engine

I'm currently working in project on rule engines and for now we have decided to use **Drools**...
What I want to know is that if there's a way to connect **hibernate session** with drool **knowledge**  **session** directly..... I mean if that's the case then we won't need to to insert facts one by one and drools will internally handle it...

Answer (score 1):

No, you should do that. If you want to obtain your facts from the database you will need to load all the facts from the database and insert them inside the ksession.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Drools can load facts on demand from hibernate or any other external service, but that is only advisable for data that is used sporadically, like reference data. For that you can use the "from" keyword. E.g.:

```
rule X
when
   ...
   SomeReferenceData() from aDataService.fetchSomeData()
...
end
```

In the above example, aDataService could be a hibernate session for instance.

But again, don't use that for the data you want to reason, as it will be impossible for Drools to optimize that if you don't pre-load it.

Comment: How about saving to Hibernate from Drools - is that recommended?